# How to perform a delete() operation in Firestore when exiting an activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have to delete 2 documents from 2 collections (without fail) whenever I exit a particular activity.

I had written the following code in onStop(), but it leads to an error for super.onStop not being called.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
       db.collection("ABC").document("123").delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                db.collection("XYZ").document("123").delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        MyActivity.super.onStop();
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean through *it led to a lot of issues related to memory leak and onStop not being called*?

Comment: The code inside the 2nd `onComplete` was not called. So an error with `super.onStop` not being called came up.

Comment: are you using ViewModels?

Comment: No, I'm not. @Pavan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it leads to an error for super.onStop not being called.

This is happening because you are placing the following line of code:

```
MyActivity.super.onStop();
```

Inside the second `onComplete()` method, which has an asynchronous behavior. To solve this, you should get that line out of the callbacks like in the following lines of code:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    MyActivity.super.onStop(); //Added outside
    db.collection("ABC").document("123").delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            db.collection("XYZ").document("123").delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

See, the call to `super.onStop()` is outside both callbacks.

Comment: Thanks Alex, in this context I wanted to understand whether the code inside the second `onComplete` be called for sure (async is okay) or is there any use-case when the code inside `onComplete` will not be called?

Comment: Yes, there is, if you don't have an internet connection on the user's device. You're very welcome, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In your approach, you are trying to trigger a background event in `onStop()` and trying to call the super.onStop() after the background work is done.

There are multiple things that make this approach invalid

- `onStop()` method can be used to trigger a background event but we cannot make the `onStop()` method wait until the background work is done. This applies to all the lifecycle methods.
- You can't use `onStop()` because the onStop method is called whenever the UI is not visible to the user, this can happen in multiple cases other than exiting activity.

> Solution

Ideally, to do some work while exiting an activity, you can use ViewModel's `onCleared()` method but since you are not using ViewModels, the other option is `onDestroy()`.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    db.collection("ABC").document("123").delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            db.collection("XYZ").document("123").delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Since we are using `onDestroy()`, we cannot wait until the background work is done and there is also another issue that `onDestroy` is not guaranteed to be called. There are some cases where onDestroy() will not be called when activity has exited.

I would prefer using ViewModel's `onCleared()` method instead of `onDestroy()` because onDestroy will be called even when there is an orientation change, which is not ideal.